# Adding UpdatePanel to aspx page

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel, scriptmanager

I would appriciate your help.
I'm trying to add an updatepanel to my page so it only refresh the gridview and not the hole page. 
i've to inseret it in different places but it doesnt seem to work, still the hole page is refreshed.
where should I insert it?

I have a dropdownlist which through I populate the gridview.
this is the code:

```
 <%@ Page Title="All Products" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="All.aspx.cs" Inherits="Catalog_All" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
    <style type="text/css">
        .style4
        {
            width: 100%;
        }
        .style5
        {
            width: 620px;
        }
        .style6
        {
            font-size: large;
            text-decoration: underline;
        }
    </style>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
<div>

  <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="True" 
                    AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DataTextField="CategoryName" 
                    DataValueField="categoryId" 
        onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
                    <asp:ListItem Value="">choose pet</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" 
                    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:AllPets %>" 
                    SelectCommand="SelectAllCategories" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
                </asp:SqlDataSource>





    <table class="style4">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" class="style6">
                <strong>All products</strong></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td class="style5">
                &nbsp;</td>
            <td>

            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

            <td class="style5">

                <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                    DataKeyNames="ProductID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" AllowPaging="True">


                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductName" HeaderText="product" 
                            SortExpression="ProductName" />
                        <asp:ImageField DataAlternateTextField="picPath" DataImageUrlField="picPath" 
                            HeaderText="pic">
        </asp:ImageField>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Price" HeaderText="price" 
                            SortExpression="Price" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Summary" HeaderText="des" 
                            SortExpression="Summary" />
                    </Columns>

                </asp:GridView>

                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
                    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:get_products_bypet %>" 
                    SelectCommand="get_products_bypet" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
                    <SelectParameters>
                        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList1" Name="categoryId" 
                            PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
                    </SelectParameters>
                </asp:SqlDataSource>


            </td>
            <td>
                &nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="style5">
                &nbsp;</td>
            <td>
                &nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="style5">
                &nbsp;</td>
            <td>
                &nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </table>


</div>

</asp:Content>
```

tahnx for the help

Comment: I couldn't see where you used the update panel

Comment: I've deleted it because it didnt work.

Comment: I added it before the <asp:gridview> .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add it right after the Content tag, up to the end, because you use the DropDownList that is make an auto full post back

```
    <asp:Content ID="Content2" ..>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updPanl" runat="server" RenderMode="Block" UpdateMode="Conditional" >
        <ContentTemplate>
       ........ rest code .........
        </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </asp:Content>
```

Comment: thanx a lot it helped. I didnt write the: RenderMode="Block" UpdateMode="Conditional"

Answer (score 0):

Try this, put the dropdown list and the gridview in the same update panel. If you don't want to put the dropdown in the same Panel, [check the second answer](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/aspnet-ajax/understanding-asp-net-ajax-updatepanel-triggers)

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="Upd">
<ContentTemplate>

      <%-- Dropdown list here should work --%>

      <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                DataKeyNames="ProductID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" AllowPaging="True">


                <Columns>
                  ....
                </Columns>

            </asp:GridView>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

If you don't want to put the dropdown in the same update panel, use Triggers

```
<%-- dropdown list outside here --%>
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="Upd">
 <ContentTemplate>
       <%-- Only your Gridview here --%>
 </ContentTemplate>

 <Triggers>
 <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="DropdownList1" 
     EventName="SelectedIndexChange" />
 </Triggers>
 </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: I've also used the triggers, maybe because of the <table> it doesnt work. could it?

Comment: No, the table can't stop it from working. Make sure you reference the right control that causes the postback in the trigger and make sure it is `asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger`